# How to change TypeLite Output Directory

Tags: typelite

Currently all of my TypeScript typings are located under `Scripts/typings/Library`.  By default, TypeLite is just under Scripts.  Is there a way to specify the output directory so it is under a custom Library name?  ie `Scripts/typings/MyCSharpProj`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeLite uses T4 templates for generating output files and I am afraid it isn't possible to change the output directory for the template. The output file is always generated alongside the template.

If you move `Manager.ttinclude` `TypeLite.tt` and `TypeLite.Net4.tt` to another directory and the output files will be generated there.

Comment: I'm assuming that would effect any attempt to update the TypeLite Library in the future via nuget, requiring someone to manually move the files to the new location?